# How would you describe this set in plain English?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To me it seems like this set is equivalent to set of all integers?

$\{n \ | \ n \ \text{is an integer and} \ n = n + 1\}$

Comment: The empty set? Or is there a typo?

Comment: I'd say the empty set as well. It's not possible to have $n=n+1$.

Comment: It's not a typo. It's a bit strange. I agree. I found this in Sipser's Theory of Computation book -- Chapter 0.

Comment: After edit. Still the empty set :) Are you trying to base something on Peano's axioms?

Comment: @CindyAnderson Not strange at all. A perfectly reasonable definition of the empty set!

Comment: Ok thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The set with no elements, i.e, the empty set.